# Using Reactive Programming RXJS with AWS SDK for javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rxjs, aws-sdk

I am using aws sdk for javascript to upload object to S3 bucket, but also using reactive programming rxjs to create streams. So what is the best way to do the S3 upload as a stream and then fire a API call as a stream?

```
var stream = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(s3.putObject(params).promise());
stream.subscribe(data=>{},err=>{})
```

In the above example, it works, but the problem is "data" is an empty object even after file got successfully uploaded to the S3 bucket, so I can't do the API stream because I need some file info.

Or should I use Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(s3.upload)? Please advice, thank you very much.

Comment: What do you expect to come back in the data object?

Comment: @MarkB shouldn't it return file info just like what is in the data object when using function(err, data)? One is a callback function and another is using promise, but how come the promise returns nothing. Am I missing something or is this a bug in AWS SDK? Thx.

Comment: Can you show an example of the file info that is returned when you aren't using promises?

Comment: @MarkB I have just read through the documentation again  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property and found out the s3.putObject function is very different from the s3.upload function. Hmmm, I will edit the question. Thank you very much man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an Observable stream from a callback, without creating intermediate promise. If you want to get the file details as a result, try using [upload method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) of aws-sdk:

```js
const upload = s3.upload(config);
const upload$ = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(upload.send, upload)();
upload$.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // will print file details
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much. I tried the fromNodeCallback before but didn't get it working because missing .send